# android - list adapter problems

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have a listview which has a textview and a checkbox in a row.

when I select a list item, the checkbox in that row is selected, in addition also an extra checkbox of different row is selected. any idea why is this happening?

my adapter where i am populating the listview:

```
public class  ContactAdaper extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context myContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;      
    private ArrayList listname;
    private ArrayList list_no;
    private List<ContactPojo> contactList;
    private ContactPojo contactObj;
    public ContactAdaper(ContactActivity contactActivity,ArrayList listname,ArrayList list_no,List<ContactPojo> listToAddContacts)
    {
        this.myContext = contactActivity;
        this.listname = listname;
        this.list_no = list_no;
        this.contactList = listToAddContacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return listname.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtMobNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);   
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.txtMobNum.setText(list_no.get(position).toString());
        holder.txtName.setText(listname.get(position).toString());


        if(holder != null)
        {
            /*holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {

                public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    //  Toast.makeText(myContext, "Selected item is :-"  +buttonView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Selected Name AND Number is :-"  +
                                holder.txtName.getText().toString()+", "+holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        contactObj = new ContactPojo();
                        contactObj.name = holder.txtName.getText().toString();
                        contactObj.mobile = holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString();

                        contactList.add(contactObj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        removeContact(holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.d("Cont", holder.txtName.getText().toString()+" = "+holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString()+" is removed from the list ");

                    }
                }
            });*/

            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
                     switch(v.getId())
                     {
                        case R.id.checkBox:
                            if (checked)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Selected Name AND Number is :-"  +
                                        holder.txtName.getText().toString()+", "+holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                contactObj = new ContactPojo();
                                contactObj.name = holder.txtName.getText().toString();
                                contactObj.mobile = holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString();

                                contactList.add(contactObj);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                removeContact(holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d("Cont", holder.txtName.getText().toString()+" = "+holder.txtMobNum.getText().toString()+" is removed from the list ");
                            }

                            break;
                     }
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;              
    }      

    private void removeContact(String mobile)
    {
        Iterator<ContactPojo> it = contactList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            ContactPojo contact = it.next();
            if(contact.mobile.equals(mobile)) 
            {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}    
class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView txtMobNum;
    TextView txtName;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

//Here is my list row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    >

 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     />
 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/id"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     />
 <CheckBox 
     android:id="@+id/checkBox"
     android:tag="tagCheck"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:checked="false"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show your layout contact_row ?

Comment: @ZouZou I have edited my question pls check it and reply

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the fact that your convertView isn't properly prepared for reuse.

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` gets called when a list item "enters the screen" (for example: during scrolling or when the view is reloaded)

The `convertView` passed to this method contains a cell that has been "moved offscreen" and can be reused for another cell to save memory. In your code, the textViews in the convertView get their values reassigned and so they will be updated, but the checkbox only gets a new listener assigned, leaving the old selection value to be rendered.
When you see the other cell being selected as well, it's this old value being loaded from the convertView.

To solve this, keep track of which rows should be selected and set the checkbox value accordingly when you create the view/reuse the converview.